# libvips extract area of NDPI from Ex40 not from map

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff, medical, vips

I am using libvips to get pyramids of .ndpi images.

through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281086/extracting-a-region-of-interest-from-an-image-file-without-reading-the-entire-im) and searching the [documentation](https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html) I found this command

```
vips extract_area myimage.ndpi[level=0] mypyramid.dz 0 0 10000 10000
```

Which extracts a crop starting at 0 0 and size 10000 10000 to a dzi file.

The `level` parameter is the magnification, 0 is the highest.

The problem is that the ndpi has the following images inside:

- myimage_macro.tif
- myimage_map.tif
- myimage_x0.15625_z0.tif
- myimage_x0.625_z0.tif
- myimage_x10_z0.tif
- myimage_x2.5_z0.tif
- myimage_x40_z0.tif

And vips is taking `myimage_macro.tif` while I need `myimage_x40_z0.tif`

There should be a parameter like level to choose which from the images inside the OpenSlide (ndpi) I want.

Some people ask. Why not extracting the tif and then running vips?

Well, because vips tells me this:

```
openslide2vips: opening slide: No such value: directory 0, tag 278
```

Which means that using [ndpisplit](https://www.imnc.in2p3.fr/pagesperso/deroulers/software/ndpitools/ndpisplit.html) to extract the tif is somehow not saving the metadata to allow vips to recognize the image

So I am in a bit of a pesky situation. I have enormous images and I need to extract a slightly less enourmous piece and then have its pyramid.

Please help me, right now I am basically coding it all my self and it works but it is EXTREMELY slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this as an answer, though it's not really an answer. It seemed too long as just a comment.

The libvips `openslideload` operation lets you pick an associated image to load. You can get a list of the associated images from the `slide-associated-images` metadata tag. For example:

```
$ vipsheader -f slide-associated-images 2013_09_20_29.ndpi 
macro
$ vipsheader -f slide-associated-images CMU-1.svs
label, macro, thumbnail
```

You then pick out an associated image with perhaps:

```
$ vips crop CMU-1.svs[associated=label] x.jpg 10 10 100 100
```

To get a small part of the label.

So ... check what associated images openslide reports for your slide. If you can get the one you need, pick that with the `associated` parameter. If the image you need is not listed, I would contact the openslide project, since they will need to add support.

You could also check the openslide command-line tools, they might perhaps offer more options.

Comment: Oh that looks fantastic, it was the "associated" keyword I was looking for. I will try it. In the meantime I already did a python script to do this for me but my DZI looks a bit weird in the smaller resolutions haha

Comment: Oh no, sadly it didn't work. I tried `vipsheader myimage.ndpi
myimage.ndpi: 226176x90880 uchar, 4 bands, rgb, openslideload` and `vipsheader -f slide-associated-images : macro` then I did `vips crop myimage.ndpi[associated=macro] macrofromheader.dz 0 0 10000 10000` and it says extract_area: bad extract area

Comment: Also for crop since crop is an alias of extract_area.

Comment: Ok so now something worked and I am at a loss why but it is good. Thank you for helping me out! What I finally ran was `vips extract_area myimage.ndpi[level=0] mypyramid.dz[tile-size=1024] 0 0 20000 20000` (which was the same from my question), but now it loads the colors properly. The only difference is the tile-size property for the dzi. I wonder if it is a bug because at first it only gave me a weird greyscale image.

Comment: Oh huh how strange. `level=0` is the default, you shouldn't need that. If you can find a smallish image which shows the problem, please open an issue on the libvips bug tracker https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/new